# Find number of lines in label with fixed length and word wrap property true

Tags: delphi, tlabel

I have a label with fixed length and word wrap property set to true. At run time that label has two lines e.g.:

```
test := 'quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
```

On Label this text displayed as two lines

```
quick brown fox jumps
over the lazy dog
```

I want to know number of lines at run time:

`#13#10` does not work.

Comment: The label won't tell you this. You could infer it by making the label auto size and checking its height. Divide that height by the height of a single line, round to nearest, and hope for the best!! I expect if you have a lot of lines then at some point that will become inaccurate. If you want to be perfect, you need to handle the wrapping manually.

Comment: I believe the number of lines will remain 1 at all times, its the painting or something that will make it appear as 2 lines. So there is no way to know this unless you handle the wrapping yourself somehow

Answer (score 0):

The [DrawText function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) can be used for this purpose.

The rest of the procedure doesn't differ so much from what David Heffernan proposes in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913556/find-number-of-lines-in-label-with-fixed-length-and-word-wrap-property-true#comment55588831_33913556).

The key here is to adopt the flags `DT_WORDBREAK` to automatically break the lines and the `DT_EDITCONTROL` to mimic the caption's text behaviour.

```
function TForm1.getNumberOfLinesInCaption(ALabel: TLabel): Integer;
var
  r: TRect;
  h: Integer;
begin
  h := ALabel.Canvas.TextHeight(ALabel.Caption);
  if h = 0 then
    Exit(0);//empty caption

  if not ALabel.WordWrap then
    Exit(1);//WordWrap = False

  FillChar(r, SizeOf(TRect), 0);
  r.Width := ALabel.Width;
  r.Height := ALabel.Height;

  if 0 = DrawText(ALabel.Canvas.Handle, ALabel.Caption, Length(ALabel.Caption), r, DT_EDITCONTROL or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_CALCRECT) then
    Exit(-1);//function call has failed

  Result := r.Height div h;
  //Assert(r.Height mod h = 0);
end;
```

Comment: This relies on the label being drawn with exactly the same method as the control uses. Doesn't it use themed or styled APIs nowadays?

Comment: @DavidH doesn't `DT_EDITCONTROL` take care of that? It shoud do

Comment: No. A label doesn't paint its text this way. Read the code of how a label paints.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Function NumberOfLines(MyLabel: TLabel): Integer;
  var
    TempLabel: TLabel;
    Pint1: Integer;
  Begin
    TempLabel := TLabel.Create(Self);
    TempLabel.Caption := MyLabel.Caption;
    TempLabel.WordWrap := True;
    TempLabel.AutoSize := True;
    TempLabel.Width := MyLabel.Width;
    TempLabel.Font := MyLabel.Font;
    PInt1 := TempLabel.Height;
    TempLabel.Caption := '';
    TempLabel.WordWrap := False;
    TempLabel.AutoSize := True;
    Result := PInt1 div TempLabel.Height;
    TempLabel.Free;
  End;
```